# Amazon EC2 Utilization

Tags: amazon-ec2

Good Day,

I would like to check what is the meaning of 'Utilisation' in Amazon EC2. If my java server is running but 'IDLE' and using less than 2 percent of CPU for example 24/7 for a month..how much Utilisation is that?

I am using this calculator
http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html

Would appreciate if someone could help me clarify. I have done quite a bit of search for this term but I have come up with nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You are being billed for your instance as long as its in a running state. It doesn't matter how much CPU usage you have.